# Ubuntu: Nvidia Applet disappeared after switching to Intel Graphics

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, nvidia, mate

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Mate. And I had some trouble getting my external Display to work via HDMI, therefor I tried switching from nvidia graphics to intel graphics using the applet in my Desktop Panel.
Now I can't switch back to Nvidia since the Applet Icon disappeared. I tried checking the Nvidia Settings, but it shows just an empty window. The Nvidia Card worked perfectly till now. How can I reactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by reinstalling lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop
```